# Выскакивает ошибка "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста в чем дело. При выполнении кода выскакивает ошибка.
Вот код:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.N;

/**
 * Created by sbeskhmelnitskiy on 02.06.2017.
 */
public class T_12 {

    static int N;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new T_12().run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\sbeskhmelnitskiy\\Desktop\\input.txt"));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\sbeskhmelnitskiy\\Desktop\\output.txt"));
        N = sc.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Human> list = new ArrayList<Human>();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            Human h = new Human();
            for (int t = 0; t < 5; t ++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j ++) {
                    h.coord[t][j] = sc.nextInt();
                }
            }
            list.add(h);
        }
        check_human (list.get(0));
    }

    public int check_human(Human hum) throws Exception {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                hum.straight[i][0] = (hum.coord[0][1] - hum.coord [i][1])/(hum.coord[0][0] - hum.coord[i][0]);
                hum.straight[i][1] = hum.coord [1][1] - hum.straight[i][0] * hum.coord [1][0];
            }
     return 0;
    }
}


public class Human {
/*    public double x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4;*/
    public int [][] coord = new int [5][2];
    double[][] straight = new double[4][2];
}
```

Вот ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
  at T_12.check_human(T_12.java:37)
  at T_12.run(T_12.java:32)
  at T_12.main(T_12.java:15)
```

Как я понял, ошибка в этой части кода, но никак не могу понять конкретно в чем именно: `hum.straight[i][0] = (hum.coord[0][1] - hum.coord [i][1])/(hum.coord[0][0] - hum.coord[i][0]);`

Если что это я узнаю коэффициент для уравнения прямой.

Comment: Нельзя делить на 0.

Comment: Добавьте проверку на ноль для `hum.coord[0][0] - hum.coord[i][0]`

Comment: Понял, спасибо!